# Implementation of shell like feature within C program using unix system calls

Tags: c, unix

Can someone please suggest what is wrong with this program.I am trying to implement shell like feature by creating a child process here. On giving a command having single word like `ls` or `pwd` it works but command with multiple words like `ls -lrt` or `who am i` is not working. There is something silly mistake that I am doing but unable to debug.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <wait.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #define BUFSIZE  200
    #define ARGVSIZE 40
    #define DELIM    "\n\t\r"

    int main ()
    {
      int i,n;
      char buf[BUFSIZE + 1] ;
      char * str = "Shell > ";
      char * clargs[ARGVSIZE] ;
      int returnstatus;
      for(;;)
      {
          n = 1;
          write(STDOUT_FILENO,str,strlen(str));

          read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,BUFSIZE);
          if(!strcmp(buf,"exit\n"))
          {
              perror("exit");
              exit(20);
          }

          clargs[0] = strtok(buf,DELIM);

          while((clargs[n] = strtok(NULL,DELIM)) != NULL)
              n++;

          clargs[n] = NULL;

          switch(fork())
          {
          case 0:
          if((execvp(clargs[0],&clargs[0])) < 0)
              exit(200);

          default:
          wait(&returnstatus);
          printf("Exit status of command : %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(returnstatus));
          for(int i =0; i <= n;i++)
              clargs[i] = "\0";

          for(int i =0; i < BUFSIZE+1;i++)
              buf[i] = '\0';
      }
  }

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: @Thomas...its not working for commands having multiple words like "ls -lrt" or say "who am i"

Comment: "not working" in what way?  What happens?

Comment: And what do you mean by "unable to debug"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth...I was expecting that this should give the output when i run the command like ls -lrt or any other command. But its giving exit statis 200 in those cases where i give the command like "ps -aux" or any other command which has more than one word. I am unable to understand why this is not working

Comment: @KundanKumar: For a start, you should simplify the test program.  For example, get rid of all the `strtok` stuff, and just hard-code the arguments.  It should be possible to demonstrate the problem in 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a space in `DELIM`.
When trying to run `ls -lrt`, you want to run the `ls` executable, with two arguments - `ls` and `-lrt`.
But your `strtok` wouldn't break `ls -lrt` in two. So you're actually trying to run a program called `ls -lrt`, and there's no such program.

Adding a space to `DELIM` should solve it.

Not that it won't be good enough for some cases. E.g. when running `echo "a b"`, you want `"a b"` to be one parameter, because of the parenthesis. `strtok` would break it into two. A real shell does more complicated parsing.